# supervisord on python 3.5 and above

Tags: python, supervisord

I am trying to setup gunicorn+pythonflask+supervisord . i am new to this supervisord.i am running in python virtual environment. i ran the command sudo service supervisor restart after i ran sudo supervisorctl reread and i got the below error.

I am using python 3.5.3 in linux debian. I installed supervisor using easy_install supervisor .
the pip version is supervisor (4.0.4)

this is my supervisor.service file

```
(poc) root@server1:/lib/systemd/system# cat supervisor.service
[Unit]
Description=Supervisor process control system for UNIX
Documentation=http://supervisord.org
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown
ExecReload=/usr/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf $OPTIONS reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=50s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

i ran supervisorectl reread i got the below error

```
  sudo supervisorctl reread
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/supervisorctl", line 6, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
        @_call_aside
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
        ws.require(__requires__)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'supervisor==3.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

when i run /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf i got the same error as mentioned above.

```
cat /usr/bin/supervisorctl
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'supervisor==3.3.1','console_scripts','supervisorctl'
__requires__ = 'supervisor==3.3.1'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('supervisor==3.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'supervisorctl')()
    )
```

please advise how to proceeds on this. is supervisor working on python 3.5 and above version
I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: It looks like `/usr/bin/supervisorctl` is being called by the system python, you can either edit `/usr/bin/supervisorctl` to change the #! line to refer to your python 3.5 (at a guess this will be `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`) installation or run it directly `python3.5 /usr/bin/supervisorctl`

Comment: I changed the supervisorctl script to add /usr/bin/python3.5 but still i get the same above error. I got the python path using  which python3.5. Any one has used supervisord in python >=3.5.3

Comment: The error you are getting is basically that the python interpreter can't find the supervisor package. I suspect you have multiple versions of python installed and using different ones to install and run it. What is the outcome of `/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -m pip freeze` (lists all installed packages).

Comment: the list is long ./usr/bin/python3.5 -m pip freeze
Gkr-Message: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
attrs==19.1.0
Automat==0.7.0
backports.csv==1.0.7
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
billiard==3.3.0.23
blis==0.2.4

Comment: Is supervisor in the list is the important bit.

Comment: No , there is no supervsior in that list.why it did nit show. as i see in the pip list.

Comment: Yep that confirms what I thought, try and install supervisor using `/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -m pip install supervisor`. Should then work.

Comment: Thank you @Tim , I am able to finally get supervisor . I am able to run this using /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf . Where as not able to run using "service supervisord start" . I have a supervisord.service in /etc/systemd/system. sudo supervisorctl reread|update showing connection refused.